# How to know the Data type of a variable of unknown type in C?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun(void *x)
{
    //what is the data type of 'x', since I could have passed float instead of 
    //  int so first I have to check datatype of this and then proceed further.
}
int main()
{
     int n=10;
     fun(&n);
}
```

You can see that we dont know the type of 'x' in function fun() so how could we find out that without using(passing) any other information in function argument?

Comment: You can't, I'm afraid. Not in pure C. You'll need to pass additional information.

Comment: C knows nothing more than that contained in the arguments type -- so in this case that it is a 'pointer to something'.  There are some mechanisms in C++ to help but they aren't going to work when passing a simple 'int'.

Comment: While not about void pointers, printf is a similar case. You send type information, in the form of a format string, to the function, so it can know the type of data it receives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C11 has [type-generic expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29#Changes_from_C99) to help you solve this problem.  You could do something like this example:

```
#define myFunction(X) _Generic((X), \
    int *:   myFunctionInt,         \
    float *: myFunctionFloat,       \
    default: myFunctionInt          \
    )(X)

void myFunctionInt(int *x);
void myFunctionFloat(float *x);
```

And then call it the way you are:

```
int n = 10;
myFunction(&n);
```

or:

```
float n = 10.0f;
myFunction(&n);
```

You will need to implement the separate target functions, but you could just do the pointer magic there and pass off to a common handler, for example.

Answer (score 2):

C does not have runtime type information. When you pass a pointer, then you pass a naked pointer - a memory address.

If you are using pointers to `void` but need to know the type, then you have to pass some additional information. Otherwise, you create different functions for different types, like `foo` that expects an `int`, `dfoo` that expects a `double` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot know the type when you cast to a void *. You have to be careful while using a void pointer, because you can cast it to any type. That is the purpose to have a void pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`C` does not allow to get the type of the variable passed by `void*`. The only thing, that you can do it is write kind of object oriented code by your self.

Probably something like this:

```
typedef struct generic_type_s 
{
    void* data;
    void  (*f)(void* data);
} generic_type_t;

void f_int(void* _data)
{
    int* data = (int*)_data;
    // Do something
}

int main()
{
   int data1 = 10;
   // Generic variable initialization
   generic_type_t gv;
   gv.data = &data1;
   gv.f = f_int;

   // Calling an appropriate function
   gv.f(gv.data);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The C way of doing this is using a tagged union:

```
typedef enum {
    // will default to TypeUnitialized if unspecified in structure initializer
    TypeUninitialized = 0,
    TypeFloat = 1,
    TypeInt
} type_t;

typedef struct {
    type_t type;
    union {
        int u_int;
        float u_float;
    };
} gen_val_t;

void fun(gen_val_t v)
{
    switch (v.type) {
    case TypeFloat:
        // process float
        break;
    case TypeInt:
        // process int
        break;
    default:
        // error
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gen_val_t ov = { .type = TypeFloat,
                     .u_float = 3.45 };
    fun(ov);
}
```

Comment: There's no way of _getting_ this information at runtime except manual instrumentation like this. So it's in no way extra.